# how to define CompositeKey for all entities using reflection in entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-fluent-api, composite-key

I'm trying to add a CompositeKey (as PrimaryKey) for some of my entities that inherited from a specific interface (IPersistentEntity).

I'm doing this using reflection to get the classes that inherited from this interface and then configuring these classes to use CompositeKey by FluentApi.

```
IEnumerable<Type> types = assemblies.SelectMany(a => a.GetExportedTypes())
            .Where(c => c.IsClass && !c.IsAbstract && c.IsPublic && typeof(IPersistentEntity).IsAssignableFrom(c));

modelBuilder.Entity(type).HasKey("Id", "Version");
```

Executing code above will result to have **Id** as PrimaryKey and **Version** as AlternateKey.
But I want to have them both as a CompositeKey.

I used to write code below to define CompositeKeys and that was okay... but now I don't know what is the difference!

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Favorite>().HasKey(f => new {f.ProfileId, f.ProductId});
```

---

**UPDATE**

I deleted my previous migrations and rebuild the solution and it works now!

Comment: What version of EF Core are you using?

Comment: I'm using 5.rc1 @atiyar

Comment: I have tested with 3.1 and it generates the appropriate composite key as the documentation of `HasKey` says. If that's not the case for 5-rc1, then you can report an issue here - https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues

Comment: Just tested with 5-rc1. It created the composite primary key (not one primary key and one alternate key) with `Id` and `Version`. You have something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: I tested it again on 3.1 and it worked... @atiyar

Comment: Thanks by the way... maybe you're right and I'm doing something wrong...